How to pass Job Max RC / Last CC to COBOL Program
Imagine there is a PGM=SORT step in a job that ends with RC=8 after execution,
I need to send that RC value (or last CC) through a parameter to a COBOL program in the next step.
How can I use/send the RC?
I've tried:
//Step2 EXEC PGM=MYPROG,PARM=&RC
Also
//     SET MYRC=RC
//Step2 EXEC PGM=MYPROG,PARM=&MYRC
And they didn't work.

You canNOT pass the return-code of a previous step as parameter to the next steps.  However if your condition is to execute the cobol program only when previous step RC=8, have a IF  RC=8 check or COND = 8 then execute the cobol program.

Unless things have changed since I last used the mainframe, as @Kolsu said you can not pass the return code to the next program.
Return Codes are a JCL thing. Normally you would use the JCL if statement
like
//  IF (SORT.RC < 8) THEN
//MYSTEM EXEC PGM=MYPROG
//  ENDIF

you could do something silly like
//  IF (SORT.RC = 0) THEN
//MYSTEM EXEC PGM=MYPROG,PARM="00"
//  ENDIF
//  IF (SORT.RC = 4) THEN
//MYSTEM EXEC PGM=MYPROG,PARM="04"
//  ENDIF
//  IF (SORT.RC = 8) THEN
//MYSTEM EXEC PGM=MYPROG,PARM="08"
//  ENDIF

